# Setting the Icon for XAML Provider

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#, icons, type-providers

To help with my learning in F#, I decided to convert one of my C# applications to F# using the XAML provider. I was able to get all the functionality I had before with minimal changes to the XAML except for the image resources. I have two windows - each that use an icon for the window itself. No matter how I try it, I can't seem to get the application to load the needed components.

The XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Totally An Application" Height="273" Width="425" Icon="Icon.ico" >
```

If I use the usual Icon setting, the XAML designer can find the file, but when I launch the application I get: **Failed to create a 'Icon' from the text 'Icon.ico'**. I've also tried "pack://application:,,,/Icon.ico" and "/Icon.ico"

The Icon is in my project root set as an Embedded Resource, altough I've tried Content and Resource just to see if I could get the error message to change.

I admit I'm little out of my element here, but I just want to get an icon in the window - surely there must be a proper way to do that.

Comment: Your icon should be included as a Resource, with "Copy to Output Directory" option set to "Copy if newer". That way you are sure that the icon will be copied during compilation. If your icon lies in another project, you need to apply the pack://application mess...

Comment: This would seem to be a defect in FSharpX's XAML Provider. I've issued a bug report on their GitHub (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/issues/273) . I'll update the question with the response I get.

Answer (score 1):

WPF resources have to be set with the build action `Resource` and not `Embedded Resource` like was the case in Windows Forms

Comment: I tried with resource and the issue continues. The weird part is that this worked when I was using C#.

Comment: Is the resource in the same assembly? If not try doing an explicit Assembly.Load on that assembly before creating the window.

Comment: The resource is in the same assembly. I'm starting to wonder if this might be something to do with the Type Provider. I was hoping to avoid using resource since this used to be a single .exe application, but I might have to use Resource if that is what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new XAML provider - https://github.com/ReedCopsey/FsXaml - could you try that to see if it works?